# Получить Rect из GameObject Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть объект на экране, как получить его как Rect? Максимальная, минимальная точка, или просто x,y,ширина, высота?

Даже если просто выделить его - появляется прямоугольник. Мне бы его размеры или координаты.

**Обновление**

Каким образом определять - не принципиально, но хорошо бы иметь возможность использовать это без коллайдеров. Не везде они нужны. Просто, допустим в 2d режиме Unity у нас есть GameObject в виде прямоугольника. Нужны его x, y, height, width. Ну, или xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax. Только Renderer-bounds-ом?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html  Объект в юнити растяжимое понятие, какие компоненты навешены? Может ты по коллайдеру нажимаешь, а может по мешу...

Comment: Непонятно, о чём речь. Скриншот покажете?

Comment: Если объект в канвасе то getComponent<RectTransform>().rect

Answer (score -1):

Если есть `boxColider`, то `GetComponent<BoxCollider>.Bounds`. Если нет ничего, даже `RectTransform`, то `Rect = (x,y,1,1)`. У `RectTransform` есть `rect`.